CD problem in linux
I burned some images, python files and PDFs to CD in Win 10 but now I'm using Arch Linux and it won't read the CD. The CD is not damaged (that is, it is good) and when I look at it with lsblk, it shows 32G, but it is 700MB and I cannot connect it via mount (noise started coming from the CD slot, I pressed the button to eject the CD and the CD spun quickly and came out).
sudo dmesg | grep sr0

[2.143778] sr 5:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 48x/48x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[2.211837] sr 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 7904.750410] EXT4-fs (sr0): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 7904.970422] FAT-fs (sr0): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 7904.970429] FAT-fs (sr0): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem

And
sudo blkid /dev/sr0

(The CD is still inserted into the computer)
I ran it and the output was empty. Do I need to try this on a computer running Windows?

I probably selected it as above on my old computer. The photo is not mine from the internet

How did you mount the CD? Note windows probably has not mounted as EXT4, and you are trying to mount it as EXT4 (a filesystem used for Linux).

Please try sudo mount -t udf /dev/sr0 /mnt

It still doesn't work, it gives an error. Thank you very much for your time. I'm new.

"it gives an error" - what error?

mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

As I said in the answer, it does not read because I selected the Live File System format in Windows.

It almost seems like your Arch kernel configuration might not have the UDF filesystem support enabled.

I enabled udf. Output: mount: /mnt/cdrom: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

It doesn't work because the Live File System format is not directly supported by Linux systems. I think I need a Windows computer but I switched to Linux because of Windows. LOL.
